# creating xsd schema to create class

Tags: xsd

I would like to generate following class structure from a xsd schema. I am new to xsd and don't how can I achieve this. Any kind of guidance would really help.

\ATable and ATableRow are abstract classes.
    public class Table: ATable
    {

```
    public class TableRow : ATableRow
    {
        public ATableRow(ATable parent)
            : base(parent)
        {
        }


        public string Symbol { get { return base.GetValue<string>("Test"); } set { base.SetValue<string>("Test", value); } }

    }

    public Table()
        : base("Table")
    {
    }

    protected override ATable.ATableRow CreateRow()
    {
        return new TableRow(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [xsd.exe documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) you'll notice that it can do:

*"Classes to XSD: Generates an XML schema from a type or types in a runtime assembly file. The generated schema defines the XML format used by System.XML.Serialization.XMLSerializer."*

You could compile your clasess into an assembly and then invoke xsd using the pattern below:

`xsd myAssembly.dll`

It could proove a good starting point, and maybe a reason for more questions...